# Possible to monitor multiple Twitter accounts and Facebook pages with widget?

Tags: facebook, app-widgets, twitter

I manage social media for a living and have finally had enough with Apple and made the switch to Android. I love it so far but there are two things I haven't had time to figure out how to do, really need to do, and am hoping someone can help with. Specifically:

1. Is there any kind of widget that i can put on my home screen that will show the most recent mentions for 5 twitter accounts and
   multiple Facebook pages?
2. Is there a way to get notifications for these same things when my phone is asleep? In other words, with an iPhone when the screen times out and goes dark, it will still pop up notifications for Twitter mentions or activity on my Facebook pages. They stay on the screen for a few seconds in case I'm watching, then the screen goes dark again. When I turn the phone on again the notification is still there until I unlock it.

I'm sorry if these seem like minor questions, but I really love my new phone and am really hoping that someone can help me figure out these two things that I really need.

Comment: There are any number of apps that work with Twitter and/or Facebook in the Play Store, including the official ones. Some come with widgets. Which have you tried? Are you sure you need a widget? The notification system will probably suffice for most of your needs.